# How to select an element in an object's innerHTML property with jquery

Tags: jquery, innerhtml

I have a function that accepts an object ( not a jQuery object ) and inside is a property innerHTML. This is a snippet of what is happening.

```
   function addToPluginList( thePlugin ){
           /* Example of what is being passed in:
            * thePlugin.innerHTML = "<h3>WP-Members</h3><span class="author"><a href="http://butlerblog.com/">Chad Butler</a></span><span class="slug">wp-members</span><span class="version">2.7.2</span><span class="description">WP-Members™ is a free membership management system for WordPress® that restricts content to registered users.</span>"
            * Need to pull out the elements inside so they can be easily accessed.
            *
            **/
           thePlugin.version = $( '.version', $( thePlugin.innerHTML ) );
           thePlugin.slug = $( '.slug', $( thePlugin.innerHTML ) );   
           console.log( thePlugin ); // no dice
        }
```

I have tried a couple of ways but ultimately what I get is this:

```
version: e.fn.e.init[0]
slug: e.fn.e.init[0]
```

And not what is expected ( thePlugin.slug = 'wp-members', thePlugin.version = '0.2 )

How would you go about this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem appears to be related to the find() method ignoring root level elements. By wrapping the innerHtml in a div the selectors start working as expected.

```
function addPlugintoList(thePlugin){
    var elements = $('<div>' + thePlugin.innerHtml + '</div>');
    thePlugin.version = $('.version', elements).text();
    //this is equivalent to elements.find('.version').text();
    thePlugin.slug = $('.slug', elements).text();
}

addPlugintoList(pluginObject);

console.log(pluginObject.version);
console.log(pluginObject.slug);
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/DX3TT/2/

There are also some other interesting possibilities for having the object itself do this work:

http://jsfiddle.net/DX3TT/9/ - this shows general prototypes for public methods to bind values.

http://jsfiddle.net/DX3TT/10/ - this will show using prototyping for creating a derived type and letting it do the binding in the ctor.

Comment: Thank you Gary, your solution worked. I would never have worked that one out.